# Any way of getting a set of all set pairs in Java?

Tags: java, combinations

Let's say I have a set with the following values: A, B, C, D. Is there an easy way of getting a set that contains AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD?

In Ruby, I can do this directly with [the combination function](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Array.html#M000759). Any suggestions on how to do this in Java?

Answer (score 2):

It's not built in to the language or standard libraries, so you'd have to code something up along the lines of [this example](http://www.koders.com/java/fidAD43F65D67DC8A5E4086DB82B622EE88B4DC2D0C.aspx).